# Solutions to the inequality $a_1 + \dots + a_n <d$

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a way to count the number of integer solutions to the inequality $a_1 + \dots + a_n <d$? If so, how would the solution vary from $a_1 + \dots + a_n <d$ to $a_1 + \dots + a_n \leq d$.

Comment: If negative numbers are allowed, there are obviously an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Otherwise, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I only allow for non-negative numbers. But the wiki page shows the case of equality. That one I understand, I'm not so sure how to extend it to the inequality case. THanks for your help !

Comment: Then count the number of solutions of $a_1+\ldots+a_d=0$, add the number of solutions of $a_1+\ldots+a_d=1$, $\ldots$, add the number of solutions of $a_1+\ldots+a_d=d-1$ and use the Hockey stick identity (http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Combinatorial_identity)

Comment: Or consider that there is a bijection between the solutions of $a_1+\ldots+a_n<d$ and the solutions of $a_1+\ldots+a_n+a_{n+1}=d$ with $a_{n+1}\geq 1$.

Comment: As you've clarified the $a_i$ should be nonnegative, this ought to be edited into your Question's body.  If you wish, one of us can do it for you.  However as asked, the problem of how solutions vary "from 
$a_1 + ... + a_n \lt d$ to $a_1 + ... + a_n \le d$" has a simple answer.  Is it really what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a dummy variable $a_0$, and count the number of nonnegative integer solutions of
$$a_0+a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n=d-1\ .$$
This is a standard combinatorial problem, and has a folcloristic name.